# Convert date with timestamp with offset value to datetime in r

Tags: r, string, time, lubridate

Say I have a character vector containing what are ostensibly timestamps in the following format:
`"20180812 17:00:00.000 -0700"` -I would like to convert that to the following
`2018-08-12 10:00:00`.

I tried the following to no avail:

```
as.POSIXct(strptime("20180812 17:00:00.000 -0700", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))
[1] NA

lubridate::ymd_hms("20180812 17:00:00.000 -0700")
[1] "2018-08-13 UTC"
```

Comment: `"20180812"` is not the same as `"YYYY-MM-DD"` (dashes!), which is not `strptime`-syntax anyway. What you're using is excel-speak, you should be using symbols like `"%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS %z"`.

Comment: Namely, `as.POSIXct("20180812 17:00:00.000 -0700", format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS %z")` works. However, your `lubridate` call *is* returning a `POSIXt` timestamp object. However, when R sees that it is "perfectly midnight" (UTC), it *represents* it as a date-like object instead of showing that it occurred at midnight.

Comment: What is the logic to get `2018-08-12 10:00:00` ? In UTC this would be `2018-08-13 00:00:00` which is what `ymd_hms` is returning.